# Maintain Form Value After Submission

Tags: javascript, forms

I have an html (no php) form on a cloud-based server. I have no access to the server files. I am struggling to do two things:

1) Show/hide div based on dropdown value (I do have this working on my site, but for some reason it's not working in my jsfiddle)

2) Maintain the dropdown value after the form is saved.

```js
//Use to hide Analysis div when analysisPub question is answered no
$('.analysisPub').on('change', function () {
    if(this.value === "Yes"){
        $("#analysis").show();
    } else {
        $("#analysis").hide();
    }
});
```

```css
/*Hide Analysis div by default*/

.analysis {
 
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Does this publication include in any form?</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="analysisPub" id="analysisPub" name="analysisPub">
     <select class="analysisPub" id="analysisPub" name="analysisPub">
        <option value="No">No</option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
      </select>
  </tr>
</table>



<!-- ANALYSIS DIV -->
<div id="analysis" class="analysis">
<h1>
Analysis Details
</h1>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><label>Project Name</label>
      </td>
      <td class="text-area">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><label>Manager Name</label>
      </td>

      <td class="text-area">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I want the div to remain hidden if the user has chosen 'No' from the dropdown, and the div should remain visible if the user has chosen 'Yes'. Currently, it doesn't matter what the user chooses, whenever the form is saved and re-opened, the div defaults back to hidden (because of the CSS).

I am very new to javascript and this project has been dropped in my lap last minute (sigh).

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 elements with the ID "analysisPub" in your markup, if you remove the ID from the td element and change

```
$('.analysisPub').on('change', function () {
```

to

```
$('#analysisPub').on('change', function () {
```

So that you are using the ID, your code works just fine.

To remember the choice you can use the localStorage API.

```js
//Use to hide Analysis div when analysisPub question is answered no
$('#analysisPub').on('change', function() {
  window.localStorage.setItem("showAnalysis", this.value);
  if (this.value === "Yes") {
    $("#analysis").show();
  } else {
    $("#analysis").hide();
  }
});

// check if value is already remembered and set it to the saved value:

if (window.localStorage.getItem("showAnalysis")) {
  $('#analysisPub').val(window.localStorage.getItem("showAnalysis"));
}
```

```css
/*Hide Analysis div by default*/

.analysis {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Does this publication include in any form?</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="analysisPub" name="analysisPub">
      <select class="analysisPub" id="analysisPub" name="analysisPub">
        <option value="No">No</option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
      </select>
  </tr>
</table>



<!-- ANALYSIS DIV -->
<div id="analysis" class="analysis">
  <h1>
    Analysis Details
  </h1>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><label>Project Name</label>
      </td>
      <td class="text-area">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><label>Manager Name</label>
      </td>

      <td class="text-area">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Luca - this worked great for my first issue, thank you! Do you know how I can maintain the dropdown value once the form is submitted? Or should I submit a new question for that?

Comment: Edited it. THe localStorage API doesn't work here though

Comment: It's still not working. I added your code, set Analysis to 'Yes', saved the form, and when I opened it up the Analysis section was hidden again (I'm guessing because the CSS has analysis set to hide). It seems like the JS and the CSS are in conflict....?